# Script Search/replace for Indesign

Tags: javascript, search, replace, adobe-indesign

I need some help in improving my `InDesign` documents. In my company, we agreed on certain ways to write abbreviations. 
For example:

`e.g. no blank` 
(or)
`e.<0x0020>g. (blank)`

I need a script that searches the opened InDesign document for those versions of e.g. and replaces them all by `e.<0x200A>g (hair blank)`.

I tried doing this by grep and javascript:

```
{
app.loadFindChangeQuery ('grepstyleexample1', SearchModes.grepSearch); 
app.activeDocument.changeGrep();
app.loadFindChangeQuery ('grepstyleexample2', SearchModes.grepSearch); 
app.activeDocument.changeGrep();<br>
}
```

but it just doubles the work.

From what I got on the net is that I need to define a string, but the examples only showed sample sentences and no indication how to define the search string to the active `InDesign` document.
I m a total newvieAny hints on how to do this?
Help is very much appreciated! 
Thanks!

Comment: So, you want to _programmatically_ edit a document in this manner? Because the InDesign editors do support a "grep" interface that might just be the path of least resistance.

Comment: @jdv Yes but that would mean (because we have alot of abbreviations) i´d have to save a humongous amount of grepstyles to execute in the script mentioned above, or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, you have to know what pattern you want to match, and what you want to replace it with. You'd have to read the docs, but it looks like InDesign Grep supports metacharacters that turn 1:1 text search and replaces into something more like regular expressions or "globbing". However, you should be clear in your question about what your question is. Are you talking about using an InDesign editor with Grep support, or are you talking about programmatically replacing markup in a document using a scripting language and an API that allows that language to read and write InDesign docs.

Comment: But, in general, you will have to construct a set of patterns and replacements that fit your needs. Some of your changes will be similar in nature, and your expressions will capture more than one (maybe). But at the end of the day you are trying to automate editing document metadata. At some point we all have to consider if this is worth the time: https://xkcd.com/1205/ and of course: https://xkcd.com/1319/

Comment: @jdv Nice charts! But according to them I have a lot of time to fix the issue. As it looks now, I ´ll probably define grep patterns and combine them in a script. The time saving benefit is huge! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Should you choose to do it programatically:

```
//Clear Grep preferences
app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;

//Set options
app.findChangeGrepOptions.includeFootnotes = false;
app.findChangeGrepOptions.includeHiddenLayers = false;
app.findChangeGrepOptions.includeLockedLayersForFind = false;
app.findChangeGrepOptions.includeLockedStoriesForFind = false;
app.findChangeGrepOptions.includeMasterPages = false;

//Search for pattern and replace    
app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = "my search pattern";
app.changeGrepPreferences.changeTo = "replacement string";
myDocument.changeGrep();

//Clear Grep preferences
app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;

//perform next search
```